# How To Build Custom jQuery Easing/Bounce Animations?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate, easing

I am familiar with the jQuery animate function and I have also gone through the various [jQuery UI easing functions](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html). Unfortunately none of them appear as the same animation effect I'm looking for so is it possible to create your own easing functions?

The animation I am attempting can be seen on the [Apple Mac webopage](http://www.apple.com/mac/) with the dynamically loaded products widget at the top. The initial items appear to slide in from the top and then give a bounce-back effect after landing in place. Is it possible to recreating this easing style using custom jQuery code? Or possibly build your own 3rd party easy functions?

I've included a screen of what I'm talking about and hopefully somebody can offer a solution. Thanks in advance :)

[image: Mac animated menu]

[image: highlighted graphics]

Comment: Have a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916058/jquery-easing-function-variables-comprehension it should help you to understand how to build or add an easing type to the easing functions. http://forrst.com/posts/How_to_create_custom_jQuery_easing_functions-OKb

Comment: Anyone looking into this the animation javascript on the page is at http://images.apple.com/global/scripts/productbrowser.js and animation is added at line addVendorEventListener("animationStart",m); for each of elements in product grid.

Comment: The fact that the example page you gave doesn't work the same in IE (below ver. 10) suggests it's actually (mostly) CSS animated. Just a few items are actually animated using JavaScript/JQuery, such as individual DIVs containing product categories sliding into view, and that caret at the bottom also seems to be animated by using JS. Have a look at the [Animate.css examples](http://daneden.me/animate/) to see if any of those would fit your needs or if you could _'roll your own'_ based on CSS animation/transformation techniques described therein.

Comment: @FarrukhSubhani - Looks like it is accomplished via CSS animation: http://images.apple.com/global/styles/productbrowser.css `Line 169` to `Line 340`

Comment: @Derek thank you this does appear to be correct.. I was fairly confident this animation was built on JS but I'll have to play around using the source code.

Comment: @Derek I'm looking through all the keyframes and unfortunately I am very unfamiliar with this technique. Do you have any recommended articles to check out? I am just struggling to understand how they force the animation to load right after the DOM finishes. Usually CSS3 animations require some type of event like hover or focus. But keyframes must be a different story - I'll keep digging but thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @JakeRocheleau - MDN has an [article on CSS animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Tutorials/Using_CSS_animations) and it did a great job explaining it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See my **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/gtfkm/)**

The main idea is performing 2 continuous animations using **[easeOutCubic](http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/effect/easing.html)** effect:

HTML:

```
<div class='left'></div>
<div class='center'></div>
<div class='right'></div>
```

JS:

```
$('div.left').animate({top: 410, left: 10}, 300, "easeOutCubic", function(){
    $('div.left').animate({top: 400, left: 20}, 300, "easeOutCubic");
});

$('div.center').animate({top: 420}, 300, "easeOutCubic", function(){
    $('div.center').animate({top: 400}, 300, "easeOutCubic");
});

$('div.right').animate({top: 410, right: 10}, 300, "easeOutCubic", function(){
    $('div.right').animate({top: 400, right: 20}, 300, "easeOutCubic");
});
```

Comment: This is a good solution with jQuery thanks. Enjoy the bounty! I will open another question in search for a solution using CSS3 keyframes.