# Jquery appearance with increasing

Tags: jquery, animation

Prompt how to implement animation block appearance similar to a window appears asking for the password at the Apple Store ios devices.

Here's how the animation should look: [http://youtu.be/4kqmEHNf23I?t=3m21s](http://youtu.be/4kqmEHNf23I?t=%203m21s)
I'm sure there are ready-made solutions, but the search for failed. I think in hand to write with basic skills jquery this effect is very difficult.

Comment: Question clarity aside, can you post the code you have so far

Comment: I think I understand your question to say, you want to popup a div/box that comes from the middle of the screen, expands on top, bounce/jiggles a little and then sets into place. It's basically a lightbox with easing at the end of the animation? Is that correct? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463091/how-to-build-custom-jquery-easing-bounce-animations If so, you can use something similar to this except with a show popup/lightbox, and take the easing info out of there.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It is this effect I want. Thank you for an instant reaction.

Answer (score 0):

There are a solution: [How To Build Custom jQuery Easing/Bounce Animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14463091/how-to-build-custom-jquery-easing-bounce-animations)
By the way, the person on the link will also not provide the code and described the situation on the fingers. I describe the situation instead gave the example in the video. So why cons?