# what are the different parameters in jQuery's easing functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I see jQuery's easing functions at https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js.

I see each function takes 5 paramaters but I can't figure out what all of them are and how they tie into a call to `animate`.

- `x` - ????
- `t` - current time - `new Date()`???
- `b` - the beginning value
- `c` - change in value ???
- `d` - duration

For example, I would call a function like:

```
$("div").width(50).animate({
    width: 150px
}, 2000);
```

Would this call match up like so:

- `x` - ????
- `t` - the current time at each call to update
- `b` - 50px
- `c` - 100px
- `d` - 2000

Comment: Why don't you read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) instead of the source?

Comment: @Andreas: I did but it doesn't answer my question as to what each parameter is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> x is an extra parameter not needed for the equations, but necessary for compatibility with jQuery

Reference : [link](http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/)

So `x` is equal to `null` and `t` is expressed in milliseconds since the start of the animation

I think you have right for the others.

You can see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5916058/3083093) for more comprehension

Comment: Holy crap. Thanks! The link you posted is EXACTLY what I needed. I appreciate it!